# writing to different file names using for loop in C++ visual studio

Tags: c++, file-io, ofstream

I am trying to write some data to different files for each index. i.e. The file name should change from datafile0.res to datafile99.res depending on the index passed.

I am using visual C++ 2008.

The code is:

```
void write_data(int index) {

ofstream coutput;

// first i need to convert integer index to string. Not sure if right?

ostringstream temp;
temp<<index;
std::string s = temp.str();
std::string dir = "C:\My_Data\datafile" + s + ".res";
coutput.open(dir);
```

When i run this code, the following error appears:

```
error C2664: 'void std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::open(const wchar_t ,std::ios_base::openmode,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const wchar_t *'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called.
```

Please need your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `coutput.open(dir.c_str());` reading the error message sometimes help.

Comment: Not only does this have nothing at all to do with "writing to different files" or your stated goal (even the concatenation is totally unrelated), but this has also been asked _so many times before_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your stated goal, or your concatenation.

`std::fstream::open`, before C++11, requires a `const char*`, not an `std::string`.

So:

```
coutput.open(dir.c_str());
```